# How to find the most shared species between 3 groups with DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to find the most common species ("spid" variable, which is a code made with the 4 first letters of the genus name and then the 4 first letter of the species name) in a data frame where there is different habitats (variable "hab", modalities : TA,TB,TC).

I don't know how I can apply the "max n" ("slice(which.max(n))") on each habitat to select the species that are the most common for those habitats. As an exemple, if a species has been counted 50 times in 1 habitat and 0 time in the others, compared to a species that has 10 counts in each habitat, the last one would be the more common.

Here is the code I started with :

```
brk %>% 
  dplyr::select(spid,hab)%>%
  dplyr::group_by(spid) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(n = length(unique(hab))) %>% 
  filter(n == 3)
```

As first I thought to filter the species that are in the 3 habitats but I couldn't select those species. But then how can I apply my "max" function to select the most shared species ? Is a "apply" function a good approach ?

Here is a reproductible code :

```
library(dplyr)

brk%>%
  dplyr::select(spid,hab)%>%
  dplyr::sample_n(20)%>%
  dput()

structure(list(spid = structure(c(157L, 21L, 181L, 128L, 191L, 
197L, 202L, 122L, 179L, 150L, 15L, 162L, 43L, 202L, 154L, 179L, 
57L, 229L, 231L, 183L), .Label = c("ACROEMER", "ACROMEGA", "AEROSUBPM", 
"AMAZDIPL", "ANASAURI", "ANASPILI", "ANDRABER", "ANDRBILO", "ANEULATI", 
"BAZZDECR", "BAZZDECRM", "BAZZMASC", "BAZZNITI", "BAZZPRAE", 
"BAZZROCA", "BRACEURY", "BUCKMEMB", "CALYARGU", "CALYFISS", "CALYMASC", 
"CALYPALI", "CALYPERU", "CAMPARCTM", "CAMPAURE", "CAMPCRAT", 
"CAMPFLEX", "CAMPJAME", "CAMPROBI", "CAMPTHWA", "CEPHVAGI", "CERABELA", 
"CERACORN", "CERAZENK", "CHEICAME", "CHEICORDI", "CHEIDECU", 
"CHEIMONT", "CHEISERP", "CHEISURR", "CHEITRIF", "CHEIUSAM", "CHEIXANT", 
"COLOCEAT", "COLOHASK", "COLOHILD", "COLOOBLI", "COLOPEPO", "COLOTANZ", 
"COLOZENK", "COLUBENO", "COLUCALY", "COLUDIGI", "COLUHUMB", "COLUOBES", 
"COLUTENU", "CONOTRAP", "CRYPMART", "CUSPCONT", "CYCLBORB", "CYCLBREV", 
"CYLIKIAE", "DALTANGU", "DALTLATI", "DENDBORB", "DICRBILLB", 
"DIPLCAVI", "DIPLCOGO", "DIPLCORN", "DREPCULT", "DREPHELE", "DREPMADA", 
"DREPPHYS", "ECTRREGU", "ECTRVALE", "FISSASPL", "FISSMEGAH", 
"FISSSCIO", "FRULAPIC", "FRULAPICU", "FRULBORB", "FRULCAPE", 
"FRULGROS", "FRULHUMB", "FRULLIND", "FRULREPA", "FRULSCHI", "FRULSERR", 
"FRULUSAMR", "FRULVARI", "FUSCCONN", "GOTTNEES", "GOTTSCHI", 
"GOTTSPHA", "GROULAXO", "HAPLSTIC", "HERBDICR", "HERBJUNI", "HERBMAUR", 
"HETEDUBI", "HETESPLE", "HETESPN", "HOLOBORB", "HOLOCYLI", "HYPNCUPR", 
"ISOPCHRY", "ISOPCITR", "ISOPINTO", "ISOTAUBE", "JAEGSOLI", "JAEGSOLIR", 
"KURZCAPI", "KURZCAPIS", "LEJEALAT", "LEJEANIS", "LEJECONF", 
"LEJEECKL", "LEJEFLAV", "LEJELOMA", "LEJEOBTU", "LEJERAMO", "LEJETABU", 
"LEJETUBE", "LEJEVILL", "LEPIAFRI", "LEPICESP", "LEPIDELE", "LEPIHIRS", 
"LEPISTUH", "LEPISTUHP", "LEPTFLEX", "LEPTINFU", "LEPTMACU", 
"LEUCANGU", "LEUCBIFI", "LEUCBORY", "LEUCCANDI", "LEUCCAPI", 
"LEUCCINC", "LEUCDELI", "LEUCGRAN", "LEUCHILD", "LEUCISLE", "LEUCLEPE", 
"LEUCMAYO", "LEUCSEYC", "LOPHBORB", "LOPHCOAD", "LOPHCONC", "LOPHDIFF", 
"LOPHEULO", "LOPHMULT", "LOPHMURI", "LOPHNIGR", "LOPHSUBF", "MACRACID", 
"MACRMAUR", "MACRMICR", "MACRPALL", "MACRSERP", "MACRSULC", "MACRTENU", 
"MASTDICL", "METZCONS", "METZFURC", "METZLEPT", "METZMADA", "MICRAFRI", 
"MICRANKA", "MICRDISP", "MICRINFL", "MICRKAME", "MICROBLO", "MICRSTRA", 
"MITTLIMO", "MNIOFUSC", "PAPICOMP", "PLAGANGU", "PLAGDREP", "PLAGPECT", 
"PLAGRENA", "PLAGREPA", "PLAGRODR", "PLAGTERE", "PLEUGIGA", "PLICHIRT", 
"POLYCOMM", "POROELON", "POROMADA", "POROUSAG", "PRIOGRAT", "PSEUDECI", 
"PTYCSTRI", "PYRRSPIN", "RACOAFRI", "RADUANKE", "RADUAPPR", "RADUBORB", 
"RADUBORY", "RADUCOMO", "RADUEVEL", "RADUFULV", "RADUMADA", "RADUSTEN", 
"RADUTABU", "RADUVOLU", "RHAPCRIS", "RHAPGRAC", "RHAPRUBR", "RICCAMAZ", 
"RICCEROS", "RICCFAST", "RICCLIMB", "RICCLONG", "SCHLBADI", "SCHLMICRO", 
"SCHLOANGU", "SCHLSQUA", "SEMACRAS", "SEMASCHI", "SEMASUBP", 
"SERPCYRT", "SOLEBORG", "SOLEONRA", "SOLESPHA", "SPHATUMI", "SPHEMINU", 
"SYRRAFRI", "SYRRAPER", "SYRRDIMO", "SYRRGAUD", "SYRRHISP", "SYRRPOTT", 
"SYRRPROL", "SYRRPROLA", "SYZYPURP", "TAXICONFO", "TELACOAC", 
"TELADIAC", "TELANEMA", "TRICADHA", "TRICDEBE", "TRICPERV", "ULOTFULV", 
"WARBLEPT", "ZYGOINTE", "ZYGOREIN"), class = "factor"), hab = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("TA", "TB", "TC"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help,

Germain V

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
brk %>%
   group_by(spid) %>%
   summarise(n = n_distinct(hab)) %>%
   slice(which.max(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer

I would like to have a list with the species (the code spid) that are the most common between those 3 habitats, based on the effectif of those species in each habitat.

```
spid        n_TA    n_TB    n_TC
DREPPHYS    6        1       1  
BUCKMEMB    4        4       4 
LEIJCOLE    0        0       0
```

In this random exemple (I've a total of 246 species) I would like to make a compute on this array to select the "most common" or "most sharred species" - in this case that should be BUCKMEMB, then DREPPHYS   and finaly LEIJCOLE.

Maybe "max" function isn't a good approach ?